# CSS snap scroll property snaps beginning and end of website

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

The `snap-scroll` is working fine when scrolling through divs but the website **scrolls beyond the last div** as long as you **keep scrolling down** and vice versa **beyond the first div** if you **keep scrolling up**.

Ideally, the website must not continue scrolling beyond the first and last divs and instead should **bounce back** to the first and last divs.

Here's the [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/css-scoll-snap-d0qqw). To reproduce the issue, the website needs to be opened in a new window with the extreme right button highlighted below.

[image]

#### Note

Reproducible in Chrome, Brave, Edge, Opera, and not in Safari and Firefox.

#### Code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
      html {
        scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
      }

      body {
        margin: 0;
      }

      div {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        scroll-snap-align: start;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </body>

  <script>
    const colors = ["red", "green", "blue"];

    document.querySelectorAll("div").forEach((div, index) => {
      div.style.backgroundColor = colors[index];
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue you describe in FireFox at all, there it works perfectly. But in Chrome (and I assume all chromium based browsers) the page keeps adding some pixels of white area continuously. Perhaps height properties are expanding as you scroll. Perhaps a fixed height or max-height could fix it.

Comment: Yes, not reproducible in Firefox and Safari as well.